# Select * from users where ID=x 4000+ response times when query specific record?

Tags: postgresql

I have just moved my PostgreSQL database from Heroku to and RDS instance, with a SQL dump

Now I'm experiencing a weird sort of locking issue.

If a query has a specific record in it it HANGS , sometimes for over a minute so I get a 504 issue

User Load (43764.3ms)

```
SELECT  "users".* 
FROM "users" 
WHERE "users"."id" = $1 
LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
```

any other record on the table returns in 2-3 MS , I had this issue with record ID 3674, which I deleted and recreated solving the issue, but now it's appeared on another record ( or I've just found it and it was prevalent) .

I've rebuilt indexes, hovered and I've looked at PG_locks ( deleted possible PID) but nothing resolves.
Any query that includes this record takes forever or hangs.

Is there documentation on where to look or possible causes / solutions to try?

Comment: try a `vacuum full analyze users;`

Comment: Find the process number of the blocked backend and run `SELECT pg_blocking_pids(12345);`.